# T-SQL round current time down to the last 15 minute period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to select data from the last 15 minute period e.g:

> at 12.02 I want rows from 11:45 to 12:00
>
> at 12.09 I still want rows from 11:45 to 12:00
>
> at 12.18 I want rows from 12:00 to 12:15

The data is stored in datetime2 format and I am using 2019 standard edition. Any help appreciated to start me off. The spec may change later (e.g. 10 min periods instead of 15 min) but I'll hopefully be able to work that out myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a [DateGrouping](https://github.com/trimble-oss/dba-dash/blob/main/DBADashDB/dbo/Functions/DateGroupingMins.sql) function that I use for DBA Dash.

```
﻿CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateGroupingMins(@DateTime DATETIME,@Mins INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, @DateTime) / @Mins) * @Mins, 0) AS DateGroup
```

This can be used to round down to the start of the current 15 min period (Also end of the last 15min period).  From there you can subtract 15min to get the start of the previous period.

```
SELECT dt,
    DATEADD(mi,-15,DG.DateGroup) PreviousPeriodStart,
    DG.DateGroup AS PreviousPeriodEnd
FROM (VALUES
    (CAST('20231220 12:02' AS DATETIME)),
    (CAST('20231220 12:09' AS DATETIME)),
    (CAST('20231220 12:18' AS DATETIME))
    ) T(dt)
OUTER APPLY dbo.DateGroupingMins(T.dt,15) DG
```

Or use the DATE_BUCKET function as suggested by Paul White if you are on a new version of SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @T table 
(
    t time(0) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T 
    (t) 
VALUES
    (CONVERT(time(0), '12:02', 8)),
    (CONVERT(time(0), '12:09', 8)),
    (CONVERT(time(0), '12:18', 8));
```

Solutions:

```
-- SQL Server 2022, Azure SQL Database, Azure Managed Instance, Azure SQL Edge
SELECT 
    period_end = DATE_BUCKET(MINUTE, 15, T.t)
FROM @T AS T;

-- Others
SELECT
    period_end = 
        DATEADD
        (
            MINUTE,
            15 * 
            (
                DATEDIFF
                (
                    MINUTE, 
                    CONVERT(time(0), '00:00', 8), 
                    T.t
                ) 
                / 15 -- integer division
            ),
            CONVERT(time(0), '00:00', 8)
        )
FROM @T AS T;
```

Output:

| period_end |
| --- |
| 12:00:00 |
| 12:00:00 |
| 12:15:00 |